# scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` is being called and in which cases would I need to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Discussion
>   The scroll view calls this method at the end of its implementations of the UIScrollView and setContentOffset:animated: and scrollRectToVisible:animated: methods, but only if animations are requested.

Use it whenever you want to know about the scroll view animation ending.

Comment: So can I say that it is called when the scroll view is finished for the cases when the scroll initiated ONLY programmatically (not by user)?

Comment: It is likely that those methods are called when the user initiates the scroll.  Should be simple to test.

Comment: The reason I posted question that my test shows this method is not called in case of user scroll. So I was confused.

Comment: Ah, then yes, that may only fire in the case of programmatic movements.